# C# GridView Implementing clickable cells from dynamically created DataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been trying to work on this for awhile now, and I'm at my wits end.  I have a web form with a GridView control.  The data source is a dynamically created DataTable, and I would like to do this without Template Fields if at all possible.  My goal is to have 4 checkbox columns that the user can click to change the values.  I just made the 4 columns data type bool so that they automatically show up as checkboxes.  I know how to select a row with a little help from javascript, but being able to detect which column was clicked has thus eluded me.

Relevant code showing how I am currently selecting the row:

```
function getSelectedRow(row) 
{
    jQuery(row).children(":first").children(":first")[0].click();
}
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void gvReviewOrder_OnRowDataBound(object sender,  GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string onClick = "javascript: getSelectedRow(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = onClick;
        e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
    }
}
```

The latest thing I have tried was using JQuery from the following thread:
[Table row and column number in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788225/table-row-and-column-number-in-jquery)

Instead of using an alert, I was trying to update the clicked column index into a hidden field, so this is what my current Javascript function looks like:

```
$("td").click(function () 
{
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    $("#hfColumnId").val(colIndex);
});
```

So hypothetically my hidden field "hfColumnId" should be updated when the cell is clicked, but that is not happening.  Do I need to add code on my OnRowDataBound Event to add the click event first?

As you can probably guess, I'm still learning when it comes to web forms, and I'm just over my head right now.  Any help would be much appreciated.

So to make a long question short, is there any way to return the column index when a cell is clicked via jquery from a GridView control?

Thanks in advance!

**edit**
I found this thread from last year with a solution, but they suggest setting EnableEventValidation to false, and I know this is not recommended.  So if I could figure out how to implement that way without setting that to false it could be a potential solution maybe?

[Get clicked cell index in gridview (not datagridview) asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202877/get-clicked-cell-index-in-gridview-not-datagridview-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is described in : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/209416/Click-select-row-in-ASP-NET-GridView-or-HTML-Table :

*Listing 1. Adding onClick attribute to the Table dynamically rendered by ASP.NET GridView*

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
        // javascript function to call on row-click event
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:void SelectRow(this);");
    }
}
```

and corresponding sample `Javascript` Function to perform some custom formatting of the dynamically rendered Table `Row` on click event (essentially implementing a Click event handler):

*Listing 2. Javascript function to format Table Row onClick*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// format current row
function SelectRow(row) {
 var _selectColor = "#303030";
 var _normalColor = "#909090";
 var _selectFontSize = "3em";
 var _normalFontSize = "2em";
 // get all data rows - siblings to current
 var _rows = row.parentNode.childNodes;
 // deselect all data rows
 try {
     for (i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
         var _firstCell = _rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
         _firstCell.style.color = _normalColor;
         _firstCell.style.fontSize = _normalFontSize;
         _firstCell.style.fontWeight = "normal";
     }
 }
 catch (e) { }
 // select current row (formatting applied to first cell)
 var _selectedRowFirstCell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
 _selectedRowFirstCell.style.color = _selectColor;
 _selectedRowFirstCell.style.fontSize = _selectFontSize;
 _selectedRowFirstCell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, instead of adding onClick attribute to each row of the table as per Listing 1, it's possible to implement this functionality with Javascript code snippet shown below:

*Listing 3. Javascript Table Row onClick event handler*

```
// ** table row click event **
function row_OnClick(tblId) {
    try {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var _row = rows[i];
            _row.onclick = null;
            _row.onclick = function () {
                return function () {selectRow(this);};
            }(_row);
        }
    }
    catch (err) { }
}
```

Practical implementation of the solution shown above (Listing 3) with complete Javascript code base can be found here: http://busny.net.

Client-side Javascript (or jQuery) scripting provides high responsiveness. This core solution could be further extended pertinent to the particular requirements. For example, individual CheckBoxes within the row object var can be addressed by using the following syntax:

```
row.cells[0].firstChild.checked
```

and so on.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex, but unless I'm reading this code wrong I don't think it would work for what I'm trying to do.  My Grid View has 10 columns.  The last 4 columns have checkboxes that are checked or unchecked depending on what the underlying data is.  Let's say the user clicks in the 2nd row on the first checkbox column (which would be column index 6).  I need to have that row number and column number returned to me so that i can alter the underlying DataTable.  I can use the OnSelectedIndexChanging method to grab the clicked row, but I am having trouble returning the column clicked

Comment: You are welcome. This is just a sample demo of core client-side GridView/CheckBox  Javascript (or it could be jQuery) coding technique, providing high responsiveness (no need for server round trip). In addition to this, upon necessity, further server-side processing can be performed on "Submit" event, customized per your particular requirements. Best regards,

Comment: What would the javascript (or JQuery) function look like if all I wanted to do was return which column was clicked?  Ideally what I would like to happen is that when the user clicks in that gridview, I want that columns index to be saved somewhere (perhaps in my hidden field) so that in my code behind I can then change my DataTable information accordingly.  Thanks for your help so far.  My main skill is with c#, but the Jquery part is where I'm having most of the issues.

Comment: ASP.NET GridView control is rendered as HTML Table, thus the Cell would be addressed by the row and column index (for example row.cells[0]). As long as you can intercept the click event from Table row, you can obtain the status of the CheckBox (by its checked property) and further process this data either on client-side using Javascript (as it's done in this  example), or on the server side. In case you have more questions, please post them separately as this discussion thread is getting lengthy. Best regards,