# Highlight one gridview cell in each row when click and get those value in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How will I select one cell in each row of a `GridView`?

Suppose i have 4 price column in a gridview for different vendor against each product like below.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Product
      </th>
      <th>
        Vendor1
      </th>
      <th>
        Vendor2
      </th>
      <th>
        Vendor2
      </th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        item1
      </td>
      <td>
        15000
      </td>
      <td>
        10000
      </td>
      <td>
        14000
      </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        item2
      </td>
      <td>
        25000
      </td>
      <td>
        15400
      </td>
      <td>
        26000
      </td>
    <tr>
    </table>
```

then I want to select one price from each vendor.

Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: are you using the actual asp:GridView, because that's not how your markup would look if you were.

Comment: yes, I m using asp:gridview with autogeneratedcolumn = true. I have getting the result from the procedure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202877/get-clicked-cell-index-in-gridview-not-datagridview-asp-net